# Variable referenced before assignement in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

`This is the code:

```
Class Car:
    """un simple intento de representar un coche."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Inicializa los atributos para describir un coche."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Devuelve un nombre descriptivo con formato ordenado."""
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Imprime una frase que muestra el kilometraje del coche."""
        print(f"Este coche tiene {self.odometer_reading} kilómetros.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """Establece la lectura del cuentakilométros al valor dado.
           Rechaza el cambio si se intenta hacer retroceder el cuentakilómetros."""
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("no puedes retroceder el cuentakilómetros, hijueputa!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        self.odometer_reading += miles

    def fill_gas_tank(self, amount):
        """Indica la cantida de combustible que tiene el coche"""
        self.amount = amount
        print(f"El coche tiene {self.amount} litros de gasolina.")

class Battery:
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""
    def __init__(self, battery_size=75):
        """Initialize the battery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
        print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        """Imprime una frase acerca del alcance que proporciona esta batería."""
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range = 418.43
        elif self.battery_size == 100:
            range = 506.94

        print(f"Este coche puede circular unos {range} kilómetros con una carga completa.")

class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes of the parent class.
           Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car."""
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()

    def fill_gas_tank(self):
        """Los coches eléctricos no necesitan un tanque de gasolina."""
        print("Este coche no necesita un tanque de gasolina.")


#coche1 = Car('Ssang Yong', 'Rodius', 2015)
#coche1.fill_gas_tank(75)
#my_tesla.fill_gas_tank()

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
my_tesla.battery.battery_size = 125
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

This is the result:

> 2019 Tesla Model S This car has a 125-kWh battery. Traceback (most
> recent call last): File
> "/home/usuario/PycharmProjects/pythonCrashCourse/capitulo_9_clases/electric_car_2.py",
> line 76, in <module> my_tesla.battery.get_range() File
> "/home/usuario/PycharmProjects/pythonCrashCourse/capitulo_9_clases/electric_car_2.py",
> line 52, in get_range print(f"Este coche puede circular unos {range}
> kilómetros con una carga completa.") UnboundLocalError: local variable
> 'range' referenced before assignment
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

These are the calls for the class:

```
`

I don´t understand why it says "referenced before assignment", this is not like this, isn´t it?
I put the value before reference variable "range" i think:

> 
> my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
> **my_tesla.battery.battery_size = 125**
> print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
> my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
> **my_tesla.battery.get_range()**
> 

Thanks for your help!!!
```

Comment: Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1):

This happens because none of the conditions in the `if statement` is met, so `range` is not defined. You could add an `else` statement or whatever make sense for your settings to handle other possible battery sizes.

Answer (score 1):

In this function, if your `self.battery_size` is not 75 or 100 then the range variable never define means the `range` variable is not the code. But then you try to print the value `range`.

```
    def get_range(self):
        """Imprime una frase acerca del alcance que proporciona esta batería."""
        range_ = None     # or 0
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range_ = 418.43
        elif self.battery_size == 100:
            range_ = 506.94
        if range_ is not None:
            print(f"Este coche puede circular unos {range_} kilómetros con una carga completa.")
        else:
            pass # print something you want
```